# How to reset compressed assets in rails after config update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, asset-pipeline

I have an issue with rails assets. First time I've run it on prod with

```
config.assets.compress = true.
```

Now I want to get uncompressed assets for better debug options, but after config update and server restart still have single file for css and js.

Also remove cache manually with no effect with this:

```
rm -rf tmp/cache/assets/{*,.*}
```

What part I miss?

Answer (score 2):

There is a rake task to clean the assets, I think this removes the `public/assets` dir

```
rake assets:clean
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but doesn't work for me. (and I have not public/assets folder).